# How to check validaty of variables names dynamically generated by URI

Tags: php, uri

I am building router for my custom MVC project.

In my router, for pretty URL names, I ran into problem. What is the best practice for dealing with dynamically generated variables names via URI?

Example:

http://knjiskicrv.comoj.com/book/id/2/

Will generate:

```
$page = 'book';
$id = '2';
```

Now, problem may arise when someone deliberately start messing up with URI. Like:

http://knjiskicrv.comoj.com/book/id+one/2/

I will get:

```
$page = 'book';
$id one = '2';
```

Hope someone could give me some advice how to prevent and solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, input sanitize that url. Do not create dynamic variables from a spoofable input source. Well, you have to know, what to expect on the given page. What variables and what type of variables these hold.

What if you have to display a set of categories and one of the categories' name is 'id'

/products/monkeys/white/id/ - you are properly ...d

Choose a different convention for processing your URI.

Like divide the URI into area, section and page elements.

http://www.oink.com/products/pigs/spottyones/angry/the_big_spotty_pig.html

area = 'products'
section = array('spottyones','angry')
page = the_big_spotty_pig (this uniquely identifies the article, product etc.)

When I have to use variables, these are mostly about ordering, page nr, etc. So these can be appended as query string parameters.

UPDATE
**Sanitization:**

You have to set the rules for yourself. Let's say the URI can only contain certain characters.

```
//Sanitization 
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // /products/monkey/angry/page.html

//allow only characters, numbers, underline and dash 
if (!preg_match('~^[a-z0-9-_]$~isD',$uri)) 
$uri = '/'; //URI has been tampered with

$uriparts = explode('/',$uri); 
/* array('products','monkey','angry','page.html') */

//Do whatever you want with the uri parts ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sanitizing is my question. What is best practice? I could go crazy and go inter some loops and start hitting up conditions, but best practice, with experienced people, could very much help.

Comment: Can you explain me `~^[a-z0-9-_]$~isD`? Part of `^[a-z0-9-_]$` I do understand, but that `~` in beginning, and `~isD` at end, do not?

Comment: Thats easy, it's the delimiter character in the regexp. It can be anything. preg_match('/^[a-z0-9-_]$/isD',$uri) isD are modifiers. check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking about mitigating "Cross Site Scripting" (XSS) vulnerabilities.

That's a big topic.  And remember: there are LOTS of ways for a (potentially malicious) user to "deliberately start messing ... with the URI".

Suggestion: start reading :)

Here are some links:

http://seancoates.com/blogs/xss-woes

http://www.cgisecurity.com/xss-faq.html

http://www.uri.edu/webservices/phpGuideline.html

Comment: Good post, it's better the understand than to just know something

Answer (score 1):

You could store those variables in an array, so you get

```
$var['id one'] = '2';
```

Just my suggestion.